# Showing a bar chart with expected value and current value for a series

Tags: jquery, d3.js, highcharts

I want to show a bar chart like shown below. The bar chart has a expected value component which i need to show as a vertical line. I tried using highchart and d3 to achieve the same, but I am not able to show the vertical line as needed.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: @epoch: I tried using basic bar charts in d3 and highcharts.

Comment: thanks, but i'm more interested in what went wrong, can you show your code so far?

Comment: @epoch: I could draw the graph, but the problem is with the vertical line (which shows expected value) which I could not bring in.

Comment: It would really help if you can show the code up to the point where you could not add the vertical line.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the Highcharts marker to draw a line marker, like this:

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.vline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + height / 2,'L',x+width,y + width / 2];
};
```

Set the marker symbol to `vline` for a vertical line, `hline` for a horizontal line.

Set `lineWidth`, `lineColor`, and `radius` properties as well:

```
plotOptions:{
    scatter:{
        marker:{
            symbol:'vline',
            lineWidth:3,
            radius:9,
            lineColor:'#333'
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/boL726bq/
- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/QM6kF/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [approach](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulson/hk9tknx0/)

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Real data',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2],
        //pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'grey'
    },{
        name: 'Limits',
        data: [153, 156, 554, 408, 6],
        color: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'grey'
    }]
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
                grouping: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
```

And please provide what have you've done this far. This will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of a line chart and a grouped bar chart I think the chart shown in the image can be obtained.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/91917yrv/) is my sample

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            type: 'bar',
            color: 'transparent'
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
            type: 'bar',
            color: '#00BB00'
        },{
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8],
            lineWidth: 0,
                color: 'black',
                marker: {
                symbol: 'square',
                width: 10,
                height: 1

            }
        }]
```

I hope this will help you to get your chart.